# Global to local transformation matrix in 2D frame structures

Tags: finite-element

In section 3.2 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11081-013-9225-7) [1], where 2D planar frame structures are being analyzed, the authors mentioned a transformation matrix to be used in extracting the element displacement vector from the displacement vector of the ground structure in global coordinates.

$u_i^e = (u_x^{(1)},u_y^{(1)}, \theta^{(1)},u_x^{(2)},u_y^{(2)}, \theta^{(2)})$ is the element $i$'s displacement vector in local coordinates.
$$u_i^e=T_i u$$
where $T_i \in \mathbb{R}^ {6\times d}$. What should be the matrix $T_i$?

**Note:** The same matrices are used to assemble the global stiffness matrix from elements stiffness matrix in local coordinates using the following formula:
$$K= \sum_{i\in E}\sum_{j=1}^3 k_{ij}b_{ij}b_{ij}^\top$$
where $b_{i1}, b_{i2},b_{i3}\in \mathbb{R}^d$ are defined by ($\hat{b_{ij}}$ are $6\times 1$ constant vectors):

$$b_{ij}=T_i^\top \hat{b_{ij}}$$

I am not an expert in statics or mechanical concepts but I need these relations for the optimization problem that I am using for my research.

[1] Kureta, Rui, and Yoshihiro Kanno. "A mixed integer programming approach to designing periodic frame structures with negative Poisson’s ratio." Optimization and Engineering 15.3 (2014): 773-800.

Comment: Have you looked at this [reference](http://www.eng.buffalo.edu/~abani/fem/node6.html)?

Comment: @nicoguaro I looked at it unfortunately it’s all about truss structures in which stiffness matrix and degrees of freedom are different from frame structures.

Comment: It's not that different. You have to transform displacements, and they transform in the same fashion and rotations that doesn't transform in this case.

Comment: @nicoguaro Can you please write as an answer the transformation matrix for an Equilateral triangle frame structure with 9 degrees of freedom(not all of them are free)? As explained in the question, T should be a 6x9 matrix...

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider that you already know how to obtain the stiffness matrix in the local configuration,

$$[K]\{U\} = \{F\}\, .$$

Now, we want to express our systems of equations in a system rotated by an angle $\alpha$.

[image]

The (generalized) displacement components would be given by

\begin{align}
&u_1' = u_1 \cos\alpha + v_1 \sin\alpha\, ,\\
&v_1' = -u_1 \sin\alpha + v_1 \cos\alpha\, ,\\
&\theta_1' = \theta_1\, ,\\
&u_2' = u_2 \cos\alpha + v_2 \sin\alpha\, ,\\
&v_2' = -u_2 \sin\alpha + v_2 \cos\alpha\, ,\\
&\theta_2' = \theta_2\, ,\\
\end{align}

or, in matrix form,

$$\begin{Bmatrix}u_1'\\ v_1'\\ \theta_1'\\ u_2'\\ v_2'\\ \theta_2'\end{Bmatrix} =
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\alpha &\sin\alpha &0 &0 &0 &0\\
-\sin\alpha &\cos\alpha &0 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &\cos\alpha &\sin\alpha &0\\
0 &0 &0 &-\sin\alpha &\cos\alpha &0\\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1\\
\end{bmatrix}}_{T}
\begin{Bmatrix}u_1\\ v_1\\ \theta_1\\ u_2\\ v_2\\ \theta_2\end{Bmatrix}\, .$$

That we can write es

$$\{U'\} = [T]\{U\}\, .$$

Thus, we have the following

\begin{align}
&[K] \{U'\} = \{F\}\, ,\\
&[K] [T] \{U\} = [T] \{F\}\, .
\end{align}

And, multiplying both sides by $[T]^T$, we obtain

\begin{align}
&[T]^T [K] [T] \{U\} = \underbrace{[T]^T [T]}_{[I]} \{F\}\, ,\\
&[T]^T [K] [T] \{U\} = \{F\}\, .
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the mentioned paper, the authors mentioned the T matrix will be a 6xd in which d is total degrees of freedom in the structure. I still don't understand how to generate such a T matrix (with the mentioned dimensions) from T(6x6) matrix of cosines that is mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me either. I would suggest that you understand the assembly process for Finite Elements, even though your research topic is centered on optimization.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and answer.